# Quarkus Panache with MongoDB: How to use the aggregate method?

Tags: mongodb, quarkus-panache

I am trying to write this query in Java with Quarkus Panache:

```
db.getSiblingDB("review").getCollection("Rating").aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
            productId: ObjectId("645ca17a0e371317308f2e09")
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id:"$productId",
            Average: { $avg: "$score"}
        }
    }
])
```

There are no examples for the aggregate method. **How do I turn this into a List<? extends Bson>?**

Edit: From the few examples I found, I tried something along the lines of:

```
public static Uni<Integer> getAverage(String productId){
    DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("productId", new ObjectId(productId)) );
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", "$productId"));
    Rating.mongoCollection().aggregate(List.of(match, group)); // <-- This does not work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AggregateIterable<Integer> aggregateIterable = Rating.mongoCollection().aggregate(List.of(match, group), Integer.class);
return StreamSupport.stream(aggregateIterable.spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Try this one.